# electron issues / Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'title' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, class, electron

I am trying to write some classes for my code (typescript, material ui, react, electron).
In codeSandbox my code runs fine, however when I am trying to execute my code in the electron environment I get a white screen. Looking at the developer-tools I get the message:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'title' of undefined"
```

I am pretty sure that 'title' is defined (otherwise it wouldn't have worked on codeSandbox I guess).
Would be cool if someone could help me.
(if you need more of my code feel free to ask :))

```
...
export default function NestedGrid(this: any) {
...
    class class_cards {
    nameOfCard: string;
    topic1: string;
    content_topic1: string;
    topic2: string;
    content_topic2: string;

    constructor(
      nameOfCard: string,
      topic1: string,
      content_topic1: string,
      topic2: string,
      content_topic2: string
    ) {
      this.nameOfCard = nameOfCard;
      this.topic1 = topic1;
      this.content_topic1 = content_topic1;
      this.topic2 = topic2;
      this.content_topic2 = content_topic2;}

  public Cards() 
    {
      //console.log(this);          //ADD.L
      return (
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Card className={classes.root} variant="outlined">
            <CardContent>
              <Typography
                className={classes.title}
                color="textSecondary"
                gutterBottom
              >
        
{/*!!! electron will only work properly if you write 'TITLE' instead of '{this.title}' !!!  */}
                
                {this.nameOfCard} {/* <----- 1st class element */}
              </Typography>

              <Accordion>
                <AccordionSummary
                  expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                  aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                  id="panel1a-header"
                >
                  <Typography className={classes.root}>
                    Topic 1 {/* <----- 2nd class element |||||||||||| */}
                  </Typography>
                </AccordionSummary>
                <AccordionDetails>
                  <Typography>Hello There</Typography> {/* |||||||| */}
                </AccordionDetails>
              </Accordion>

              <Accordion>
                <AccordionSummary
                  expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                  aria-controls="panel2a-content"
                  id="panel2a-header"
                >
                  <Typography className={classes.root}>
                    Topic 2 {/* |||||||| */}
                  </Typography>
                </AccordionSummary>
                <AccordionDetails>
                  <Typography>1+1=2</Typography> {/* ||||||| */}
                </AccordionDetails>
              </Accordion>
            </CardContent>

            <CardActions>
              <Button fullWidth={true}>
                <IconButton size="small">
                  <Alert severity="info">LEARN MORE</Alert>
                </IconButton>
              </Button>

            </CardActions>

            {/*---------------------------------Full Screen----------------------------------*/}

            <Button
              variant="outlined"
              color="primary"
              onClick={handleClickOpen}
              fullWidth={true}
            >
              Open full-screen
            </Button>
            <Dialog
              fullScreen
              open={open}
              onClose={handleClickClose}
              TransitionComponent={Transition}
            >
              <AppBar className={classes.appBar}>
                <Toolbar>
                  <IconButton
                    edge="start"
                    color="inherit"
                    onClick={handleClickClose}
                    aria-label="close"
                  >
                    <CloseIcon />
                  </IconButton>
                  <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                    Title
                  </Typography>
                </Toolbar>
              </AppBar>

              <List>
                <ListItem button>
                  <ListItemText primary="Phone ringtone" secondary="Titania" />
                </ListItem>
                <Divider />
                <ListItem button>
                  <ListItemText
                    primary="Default notification ringtone"
                    secondary="Tethys"
                  />
                </ListItem>
              </List>
            </Dialog>

{/*--------------------------------Full Screen-----------------------------------*/}
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      );
    }
  }

  //let crd = new class_cards('TITLE', 'TOPIC1', 'HELLO', 'TOPIC2', 'BYE');
  
  // ? crd1 gets the same values as crd3 ? 

  const crd1 = new class_cards(this.nameOfCard='Card 1', this.topic1='TOPIC 1', this.content_topic1='HELLO', this.topic2='TOPIC 2', this.content_topic2='BYE');
  const crd3 = new class_cards(this.nameOfCard='Card 3', this.topic1='TOPIC 1', this.content_topic1='HELLO', this.topic2='TOPIC 2', this.content_topic2='BYE');

 return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
...
       <crd1.Cards />
       <crd3.Cards />
...
```

Answer (score 0):

electron will only work properly if you write 'TITLE' instead of '{this.title}

seems to me you may have to declare 'TITLE' in all caps